# 2-way SSL with apache forward proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, forwarding, virtualhost

I'm working to set up Apache as a forward proxy with a client that uses 2-way SSL.  The basic flow is myApplication --via http--> Apache proxy --via 2 way SSL--> client.  After setting everything up, when I try to start Apache, I'm getting a "incomplete client cert configured for SSL proxy (missing or encrypted private key?)" error.  What I can't figure out is that the client cert I'm using in the SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile directive has both the unencrypted private key and the public cert already.  Any suggestions on what I'm missing and/or anything else I can try? Does the all-in-one machine cert need to have the chain in it as well?

Here's what my vhost looks like.

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
    ServerName my.domain.com

    ProxyRequests On
    SSLProxyEngine On

    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /etc/httpd/keys/machine.pem
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/keys/machine.chain.crt

    ProxyPass / https://target.client.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://target.client.com/

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: I updated the basic flow to clarify what kind of connection I'm trying to use between the application, apache, and the client.

Comment: what is 2-way-SSL?

Comment: Is the private key in `machine.pem` DES encrypted (the default when generating)?

Comment: The all-in-one machine cert should not need to have the chain in it. I would start by trying to connect using without apache, e.g. by doing `openssl s_client -connect remoteserver:443 -cert /etc/httpd/keys/machine.pem`. The output from that should give you some hint.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I'm going to say yes.  When I generated the key and csr it was a pretty standard generation process and I didn't put a password on the private key.

Comment: @JennyD I tried out your suggestion and was able to successfully connect to the remote server using machine.pem.  However, I still can't start Apache when using machine.pem as the SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile.

Comment: @thatguyfromoverthere 2-way SSL is more or less client/server authentication.  As opposed to normal SSL where just the server verifies it's identity to the client, in 2-way SSL both the client and server present each other a certificate to verify who they are.

Comment: @MikeLevy That means that at least the key is a valid SSL key. That means that the next thing to check is whether the key is encrypted. It is possible to encrypt a key without a password; you can do the same with e.g. SSH keys by simply not entering the password when prompted. So the next question is, how exactly did you create the key?

Comment: @JennyD It actually turns out that what was going on was a discrepancy in terms between me and the client.  When they referred to installing a "key", I was thinking the SSL key, but the client was actually talking about install the public certificate.  To get things working, I actually removed the SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile directive and all I'm using is the SSLProxyCACertificateFile directive and use the public SSL cert for the site.  I'm not 100% sure that it's really 2-way SSL, but it works for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your PEM file is not the correct format. Checkout this post.

http://projectzme.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/tip-sslproxymachinecertificatefile-returns-missing-or-encrypted-private-key/